# How Set Expiry Date for my web Application?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am creating web application using jsp,servlet,javascript,etc.And I hosted that application in Tomcat server and my problem is I need to set expiry date to that application.

Application will not work after the some days.How can I set the expiry date for my application.

Can any one tell me the idea's to do this.

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: @ScaryWombat it was like licence expiry.after some days that application must not access by the client machine

Comment: Consider using a servlet Filter see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-writing-filters.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filter, e.g.

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class ExpireFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Date expire = new Date(1420092000000L); // 2015-01-01
        Date now = new Date();
        if (now.before(expire)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response); // On time
        } else {
            response.getWriter().print("Application expired!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

}
```

Comment: suggest using Calendar to construct expire date rather than hard coded long value.

Comment: Thank you Paul it gives me some ideas